# C++ - unable to start correctly (0xc0150002)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv

I'm trying to run an `OpenCV` application through `Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Express`, and get the following message:

[image]

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Did the program crash on the development computer with this message or on another computer?

Comment: Does any of these help? http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/Vsexpressvc/thread/fd4be16f-35b7-42c5-9f95-498870599d1e

Comment: @Fox32. On the development computer

Comment: It is an installation problem.  The Windows event log tells you what is wrong.

Answer (score 13):

I agree with Brandrew, the problem is most likely caused by some missing dlls that can't be found neither on the system path nor in the folder where the executable is. Try putting the following DLLs nearby the executable:

- the Visual Studio C++ runtime (in VS2008, they could be found at places like C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\redist\x86.) Include all 3 of the DLL files as well as the manifest file.
- the four OpenCV dlls (cv210.dll, cvaux210.dll, cxcore210.dll and highgui210.dll, or the ones your OpenCV version has)
- if that still doesn't work, try the debug VS runtime (executables compiled for "Debug" use a different set of dlls, named something like msvcrt9d.dll, important part is the "d")

Alternatively, try loading the executable into Dependency Walker ( http://www.dependencywalker.com/ ), it should point out the missing dlls for you.

Answer (score 13):

In my case, [Visual Leak Detector](https://vld.codeplex.com/) I was using to track down memory leaks in Visual Studio 2015 was missing the Microsoft manifest file `Microsoft.DTfW.DHL.manifest`, see link [Building Visual Leak Detector](https://github.com/KindDragon/vld/wiki/Building-Visual-Leak-Detector-from-Source) all way down. This file must be in the folder where `vld.dll` or `vld_x64.dll` is in your configuration, say `C:\Program Files (x86)\Visual Leak Detector\bin\Win32`, `C:\Program Files (x86)\Visual Leak Detector\bin\Win64`, `Debug` or `x64/Debug`.

Comment: Faced mentioned issue by OP.
Fixed by copying all dlls and manifest file to binary file to executable directory.

Answer (score 2):

Just run .exe file in dependency walker( http://dependencywalker.com/)
and it will point you the missing dlls and download those dll (www.dll-files.com) and paste in the c:windows:system32 and the folder as your .exe and even provide the path of those dll in path variable.

Answer (score 1):

I take it that is a Vista Window! I often got this when first trying to port a DirectX program from XPsp3 to Vista.

It's a .dll problem. The OpenCV runtime.dll will call upon a system.dll that will be no longer shipped Vista, so unfortunately you will have to to a bit of hunting to find which system.dll it's trying to find. (system.dll could be vc2010 or vista)

This error is also caused by incorrect installation of .dlls (i.e not rolling out)
hth
Happy hunting

Comment: I'm using `Windows 7`. Is it similar? The solution I mean

Comment: @user588855 The error number is the same on XP, in my case it was just a matter of getting the client to update their DirectX library. Latanius' link to dependency walker looks like a good place for further investigation. HTH

Answer (score 1):

I got this error when trying to run my friend's solution file by visual studio 2010 after convert it to 2010 version. The fix is easy, I create new project, right click the solution to add existing .cpp and .h file from my friend's project. Then it work.

Answer (score 0):

Even I faced same error, I fixed it afterwards...
Two things you need to look into

1. Whether your system path is correctly set in your environment variables
2. Check the pre-processors in Project Properties->c/c++->Pre-processors. Check whether you have included `_CONSOLE`, this was causing error for me. For Some applications you need to include `WIN32;_WINDOWS;_CONSOLE;_DEBUG;QT_DLL;QT_GUI_LIB;QT_NETWORK_LIB;QT_CORE_LIB;COIN_DLL;SOQT_DLL;QT_DEBUG;`

I got this error while I was working in coin3D Application.

Answer (score 0):

I met such problem. Visual Studio 2008 clearly said: problem was caused by libtiff.dll. It cannot be loaded for some reasom, caused by its manifest (as a matter of fact, this dll has no manifest at all). I fixed it, when I had removed libtiff.dll from my project (but simultaneously I lost ability to open compressed TIFFs!). I recompiled aforementioned dll, but problem still remains. Interesting, that at my own machine I have no such error. Three others comps refused to load my prog. Attention!!! Here http://www.error-repair-tools.com/ppc/error.php?t=0xc0150002 one wise boy wrote, that this error was caused by problem with registry and offers repair tool. I have a solid guess, that this "repair tool" will install some malicious soft at your comp.

Answer (score 0):

It is because there is a DLL that your program is missing or can't find.

In your case I believe you are missing the openCV dlls. You can find these under the "build" directory that comes with open CV. If you are using VS2010 and building to an x86 program you can locate your dlls here under "opencv\build\x86\vc10\bin". Simply copy all these files to your Debug and Release folders and it should resolve your issues.

Generally you can resolve this issue using the following procedure:

1. Download Dependency Walker from here: http://www.dependencywalker.com/
2. Load your .exe file into Dependency Walker (under your projects Debug or Release folder), in your case this would be DisplayImage.exe
3. Look for any DLL's that are missing, or are corrupt, or are for the wrong architecture (i.e. x64 instead of x86) these will be highlighted in red.
4. For each DLL that you are missing either copy to your Debug or Release folders with your .exe, or install the required software, or add the path to the DLLs to your environment variables (Win+Pause -> Advanced System Settings -> Environment Variables)

Remember that you will need to have these DLLs in the same directory as your .exe. If you copy the .exe from the Release folder to somewhere else then you will need those DLLs copied with the .exe as well. For portability I tend to try and have a test Virtual Machine with a clean install of Windows (no updates or programs installed), and I walk through the Dependencies using the Dependency Walker one by one until the program is running happily.

This is a common problem. Also see these questions:

[Can't run a vc++, error code 0xc0150002](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10161749/cant-run-a-vc-error-code-0xc0150002)

[The application was unable to start (0xc0150002) with libcurl C++ Windows 7 VS 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13934357/the-application-was-unable-to-start-0xc0150002-with-libcurl-c-windows-7-vs-2)

[0xc0150002 Error when trying to run VC++ libcurl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22301929/0xc0150002-error-when-trying-to-run-vc-libcurl?rq=1)

[The application was unable to start correctly 0xc150002](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8486017/the-application-was-unable-to-start-correctly-0xc150002?rq=1)

[The application was unable to start correctly (0*0150002) - OpenCv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9341817/the-application-was-unable-to-start-correctly-00150002-opencv?rq=1)

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

In our case (next to trying Dependency Walker) it was a faulty manifest file, mixing 64 bits and 32 bits. We use two extra files while running in Debug mode: dbghelp.dll and Microsoft.DTfW.DHL.manifest.
The manifest file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<!-- $Id -->
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
    <noInheritable />
    <assemblyIdentity type="win32" name="Microsoft.DTfW.DHL" version="6.11.1.404" processorArchitecture="x86" />
    <file name="dbghelp.dll" />
</assembly>
```

Notice the 'processorArchitecture' field. It was set to "amd64" instead of "x86". It's probably not always the cause, but in our case it was the root cause, so it may be helpful to some. For 64-bit runs, you'll want "amd64" in there.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue, when I was supplying the executable folder with a, by the .exe requested DLL.
In my case, the DLL I supplied to the .exe was searching for another necessary DLL which was not available.
The searching DLL was not capable of telling that it can not find the necessary DLL.

You might check the DLLs you're loading and the dependencies of these DLL's.

Answer (score -1):

Here is my solution for this error:

> (The Application was unable to start correctly (OXO15OOO20).Click to close the application).

1. From the Start menu, click Administrative Tools, and then click Windows Server Backup.
2. Click File, Click Option, and then in Disk Cleanup press Delete files and then press O.K,
   and delete till it reaches to 0 byete

No Worry About it just it deletes the amount of disk space on your computer.