# The application was unable to start correctly 0xc150002

Tags: visual-studio-2010, opencv

Hey guys so I have combed the internet trying to find a solution to my problems I had decided  I want to learn to opencv and am having a hell of a time to get a basic hello world program working.

So I'll start of with I downloaded the OpenCV2.1 from sourceforge
http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-win/2.1/

I am currently running Visual studio 2010 on Windows 7, 32 bit.

So I installed ran the OpenCV2.1.exe file and added OpenCV to my path enviroment, I then build the libraries using cmake and ran through the following instructions
http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/VisualC%2B%2B_VS2010_CMake

When i build the code in the tutorial abovei get a sucesfull build but when I try and start the program i get the "The application was unable to start correctly 0xc150002" error. Anyone have any thought ?

EDIT:
I looked at the event log and this is the information i get

Activation context generation failed for "C:\OpenCV2.1\bin\cxcore210d.dll". Dependent Assembly Microsoft.VC90.DebugCRT,processorArchitecture="x86",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",type="win32",version="9.0.21022.8" could not be found. Please use sxstrace.exe for detailed diagnosis.

Microsoft.VC90.DebugCRT,processorArchitecture="x86",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",type="win32",version="9.0.21022.8"

C:\OpenCV2.1\bin\cxcore210d.dll

Comment: Look in the Windows event log for the exact reason.

Comment: `I then build the libraries`: they were not rebuilt.  VC90 is the previous version of VS.

Comment: Ok, so this means that when I though I built the libs some failed to build? Or does this mean that this VC90 Lib is somthing that Microsoft failed to include in the new version of VS?

Comment: Ever get this working?  I'm having the same problem

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem. Indeed I did rebuild the Dlls, but in the PATH environment variable of Windows the old DLLs C:\OpenCV2.1\bin; were before the new built DLLs C:\OpenCV2.1\build\bin\Debug; which meant that always the old were loaded ... Now it works