# Can't run a vc++, error code 0xc0150002

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, dll

I'm trying to run a vc++ application on Win7 enterprise, VS2010 ultimate version 4.0.30319 but fail to do so.
The app fails on runtime stating: The application was unable to start correctly (0xc0150002). Click OK to close the application.

I guess i'm missing a system DLL, but don't know where to get it from.

The exact same project (same dll's, lib files and h files) runs on different similar machines (x64, vs2010), but fails to run on mine.
I also ran dependcy walker and this is what I've got:

```
*****************************| System Information |*****************************

Dependency Walker:       2.2.6000 (64-bit)
Operating System:        Microsoft Windows NT/2000/XP/2003/Vista based Enterprise (64-bit)
OS Version:              6.01.7601 Service Pack 1
Processor:               Intel64 Family 6 Model 42 Stepping 7, GenuineIntel, ~2594MHz
Number of Processors:    4, Mask: 0x000000000000000F
Local Date:              Sunday, April 15, 2012
Memory Load:             92%
Physical Memory Total:   4,200,972,288 (4007 MB)
Physical Memory Used:    3,884,187,648
Physical Memory Free:    316,784,640
Page File Memory Total:  8,400,052,224
Page File Memory Used:   4,405,301,248
Page File Memory Free:   3,994,750,976
Virtual Memory Total:    8,796,092,891,136
Virtual Memory Used:     200,855,552
Virtual Memory Free:     8,795,892,035,584
Page Size:               0x00001000 (4,096)
Allocation Granularity:  0x00010000 (65,536)
Min. App. Address:       0x0000000000010000 (65,536)
Max. App. Address:       0x000007FFFFFEFFFF (8,796,092,956,671)

Side-by-Side components (Windows 2000/XP/2003/Vista/+)
   [F ] c:\windows\winsxs\amd64_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_5.82.7601.17514_none_a4d6a923711520a9\COMCTL32.DLL
   [F ] c:\windows\winsxs\amd64_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.7601.17514_none_fa396087175ac9ac\COMCTL32.DLL
   [F ] c:\windows\winsxs\amd64_microsoft.windows.gdiplus_6595b64144ccf1df_1.1.7601.17514_none_2b24536c71ed437a\GDIPLUS.DLL
The system's "KnownDLLs" list
   [F ] c:\windows\system32\ADVAPI32.DLL
   [F ] c:\windows\system32\CFGMGR32.DLL
   [F ] c:\windows\system32\CLBCATQ.DLL
   [F ] c:\windows\system32\COMCTL32.DLL
   [F ] c:\windows\system32\COMDLG32.DLL
   [F ] c:\windows\system32\CRYPT32.DLL
   [F ] c:\windows\system32\DEVOBJ.DLL
   [F ] c:\windows\system32\DIFXAPI.DLL
   [F ] c:\windows\system32\GDI32.DLL
   [F ] c:\windows\system32\IERTUTIL.DLL
   [F ] c:\windows\system32\IMAGEHLP.DLL
   [F ] c:\windows\system32\IMM32.DLL
   [F ] c:\windows\system32\KERNEL32.DLL
   [F ] c:\windows\system32\KERNELBASE.DLL
   [F ] c:\windows\system32\LPK.DLL
   [F ] c:\windows\system32\MSASN1.DLL
   [F ] c:\windows\system32\MSCTF.DLL
   [F ] c:\windows\system32\MSVCRT.DLL
   [F ] c:\windows\system32\NORMALIZ.DLL
   [F ] c:\windows\system32\NSI.DLL
   [F ] c:\windows\system32\NTDLL.DLL
   [F ] c:\windows\system32\NTDLL.DLL
   [F ] c:\windows\system32\OLE32.DLL
   [F ] c:\windows\system32\OLEAUT32.DLL
   [F ] c:\windows\system32\PSAPI.DLL
   [F ] c:\windows\system32\RPCRT4.DLL
   [F ] c:\windows\system32\SECHOST.DLL
   [F ] c:\windows\system32\SETUPAPI.DLL
   [F ] c:\windows\system32\SHELL32.DLL
   [F ] c:\windows\system32\SHLWAPI.DLL
   [F ] c:\windows\system32\URLMON.DLL
   [F ] c:\windows\system32\USER32.DLL
   [F ] c:\windows\system32\USP10.DLL
   [F ] c:\windows\system32\WININET.DLL
   [F ] c:\windows\system32\WINTRUST.DLL
   [F ] c:\windows\system32\WLDAP32.DLL
   [F ] c:\windows\system32\WS2_32.DLL
The application's registered "App Paths" directories
The system's "PATH" environment variable directories
   [  ] C:\Oracle11gR2_x64\product\11.2.0\client_1\bin\
   [  ] C:\Windows\system32\
   [  ] C:\Windows\
   [  ] C:\Windows\System32\Wbem\
   [  ] C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
   [  ] C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\
   [  ] C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\syswow64\
   [  ] C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\
   [  ] C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\
   [  ] C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\
   [  ] C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\
   [  ] C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\
   [  ] C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\
   [  ] C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\
   [  ] C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\
   [  ] C:\GTK2-Runtime\bin\
   [  ] c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\
   [  ] C:\Program Files\OpenCV2.3\build\bin\
   [  ] C:\Program Files\OpenCV2.3\build\x64\vc10\bin\
   [  ] C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x86\
   [  ] C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x64\

***************************| Module Dependency Tree |***************************
*                                                                              *
* Legend: F  Forwarded Module   ?  Missing Module        6  64-bit Module      *
*         D  Delay Load Module  !  Invalid Module                              *
*         *  Dynamic Module     E  Import/Export Mismatch or Load Failure      *
*                               ^  Duplicate Module                            *
*                                                                              *
********************************************************************************

[   ] GRASPVIEWER.EXE
     [   ] OPENCV_CORE230D.DLL
          [ E6] KERNEL32.DLL
               [FE6] NTDLL.DLL
          [ ? ] MSVCP90D.DLL
          [   ] LIBMMDD.DLL
               [ E6] KERNEL32.DLL
                    [FE6] NTDLL.DLL
          [ ? ] MSVCR90D.DLL


...


********************************| Module List |*********************************
*                                                                              *
* Legend: D  Delay Load Module   ?  Missing Module           6  64-bit Module  *
*         *  Dynamic Module      !  Invalid Module                             *
*                                E  Import/Export Mismatch or Load Failure     *
*                                                                              *
********************************************************************************
[ ? ]  MSVCP90D.DLL     Error opening file. The system cannot find the file specified (2).
[ ? ]  MSVCR90D.DLL     Error opening file. The system cannot find the file specified (2).
[D? ]  IESHIMS.DLL      Error opening file. The system cannot find the file specified (2).

...

************************************| Log |*************************************

Error: The Side-by-Side configuration information for "c:\users\ ...\OPENCV_CORE230D.DLL" contains errors. The application has failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is incorrect. Please see the application event log or use the command-line sxstrace.exe tool for more detail (14001).
Error: The Side-by-Side configuration information for "c:\users\ ...\debug\HANDSD.DLL" contains errors. The application has failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is incorrect. Please see the application event log or use the command-line sxstrace.exe tool for more detail (14001).
Error: The Side-by-Side configuration information for "c:\users\ ... \debug\CORE.DLL" contains errors. The application has failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is incorrect. Please see the application event log or use the command-line sxstrace.exe tool for more detail (14001).
Error: The Side-by-Side configuration information for "c:\users\ ... \debug\OPENCV_HIGHGUI230D.DLL" contains errors. The application has failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is incorrect. Please see the application event log or use the command-line sxstrace.exe tool for more detail (14001).
Error: The Side-by-Side configuration information for "c:\users\ ... \debug\OPENCV_IMGPROC230D.DLL" contains errors. The application has failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is incorrect. Please see the application event log or use the command-line sxstrace.exe tool for more detail (14001).
Error: The Side-by-Side configuration information for "c:\users\ ... \debug\FINGERTRACKER.DLL" contains errors. The application has failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is incorrect. Please see the application event log or use the command-line sxstrace.exe tool for more detail (14001).
Error: At least one required implicit or forwarded dependency was not found.
Error: At least one module has an unresolved import due to a missing export function in an implicitly dependent module.
Error: Modules with different CPU types were found.
Warning: At least one delay-load dependency module was not found.
Warning: At least one module has an unresolved import due to a missing export function in a delay-load dependent module.
```

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks,
Omri

Comment: For example - MSVCR90D.DLL - Error opening file. The system cannot find the file specified (2).                                           - Why VC++2010 (i.e. *100.dll) needs .DLLs of VC++2008 (*90.dll)?

Comment: Indeed, is your project originally configured to build under VC++2008?

Comment: You'll need to contact the DLL owner and ask for an update.  It *must* be the Release build, you cannot run the Debug build on a machine without VS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DLL you're missing is a VS debug DLL... it is normally installed with VS. If you have a special configuration on this machine, it may be that the DLL is misplaced or simply missing. If it's missing, try to get it from your VS installer by repairing your installation.

EDIT:

If you don't need this particular DLL you can always remove the dependency in your project configuration

Comment: Thanks, I have reinstalled VS2010 but that didn't solve it. How can I remove this dependency? it is not directly referred by me, but by a different DLL i'm using.

Comment: You can't remove the dependency if it's referred by another one.

Comment: Do you happen to know which VS package contains these DLL's? Thanks