# OpenCV 2.4 on Visual Studio 2010 -- The Application was unable to start correctly (0xc0150002)

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I'm currently trying to understand the OpenCV 2.4 functions and trying to implement a few of the sample codes given. I've set up OpenCV and linked it to Visual Studio 2010 in accordance with the rules given here - http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_install/windows_install.html#windowssetpathandenviromentvariable

I'm able to build the solution without any issues, but not able to execute(debug) the .exe files generated. I keep getting errors saying that the application cannot start (0xc0150002)

I tried repeating the same after including all the dlls as mentioned here but to no avail  - [C++ - unable to start correctly (0xc0150002)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5126105/c-unable-to-start-correctly-0xc0150002)

While looking for possible reasons for this issue, I found through the dependency walker software that there are some problems with the side-by-side configuration of the opencv dlls.

Then, I came across this - http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-pictures/error-the-application-has-failed-to-start-because/df019c0d-746e-42d0-ad68-465e18e3f3ef
which asked me to install the Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package (x86). I did that but my problem still persists.

Any help regarding this issue will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You are using DLLs that were built with an earlier version of the compiler, probably VS2008.  Rebuild the DLLs from source.

Comment: I switched to Visual Studio 2008 and encountered no problems. @HansPassant : You were right, the DLLs were built using the VS 2008 compiler. To get OpenCV 2.4 working on VS2010, we have to rebuild the source files using VS2010's compiler. Thanks. :D