# 0xc0150002 Error when trying to run VC++ libcurl

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2013, libcurl

I am using Visual Studio Express 2013 on Windows 7 x64 Professional.

I followed [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20171165/getting-libcurl-to-work-with-visual-studio-2013) to setup libCurl with my Visual C++ project.

But I get the following error message when I try to run any program, even the [simple.c](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/simple.html) program fails.

**The application was unable to start correctly (0xc0150002). Click OK to close the application.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this error by installing the [Visual C++ redistributable 2013](http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=40784) package.

I installed both the x64 and x86 packages.